# MUI Autocomplete getOptionLabel return undefined when set value={} to auto Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

The following is my code for MUI Autocomplete

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
import SearchOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SearchOutlined';
import GlobalContext from '@/context/GlobalContext';

const AvailableStudents = () => {
    const [Students, setStudents] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const { formData, setFormData } = useContext(GlobalContext);

    const getOptionLabel = (Students) => (Students.Name + ' ' + Students.class + Students.classUnit) || (formData.Name + ' ' + formData.class + formData.classUnit) || "" || null

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchStudents = async () => {
            setError(null);
            try {
                const response = await axios.get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/students`, {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'accept': 'application/octet-stream',
                        'Authorization': `Bearer token`,
                    },
                });
                
                setStudents(response.data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        };

        fetchStudents();
    }, []);

    const handleOpen = () => setIsOpen(true);
    const handleClose = () => setIsOpen(false);

    const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
        setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
            ...prevFormData,
                id: newValue?.id,
                Name: newValue?.Name,
                class: newValue?.class,
                classUnit: newValue?.classUnit,
                
        }));
    };
    return (
        <div>
            {error ? (
                <p>Error: {error.message}</p>
            ) : (
                <Autocomplete
                    open={isOpen}
                    onOpen={handleOpen}
                    onClose={handleClose}
                    id={Students.id}
                    options={Students}
                    getOptionLabel={getOptionLabel}
                    noOptionsText=''
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={formData.Name + ' ' + formData.class + formData.classUnit || "" || null}
                    isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
                    renderInput={(params) => (
                        <TextField
                            {...params}
                            label={
                                <span style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <SearchOutlinedIcon style={{ marginRight: 8 }} />
                                    Search
                                </span>
                            }
                        />
                    )}
                    ListboxProps={{ className: 'Students-listbox' }}
                />
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default AvailableStudents;
```

The problem is in the `value={formData.Name + ' ' + formData.class + formData.classUnit || "" || null}`

I want to display the selected value from the state i.e. if you change to component, this value still there. Unfortunately when I add the

```
value={formData.Name + ' ' + formData.class + formData.classUnit || "" || null}
```

to the code I get undefined,undefiende in Autocomplete
[image]